# DATABASE insert and select problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

why I find it difficult to **insert more than 7 values in table** ? *when i select it retrieves only 7 values*

Comment: We can't possibly know why you find it difficult to insert data into a database.

Comment: More info please, example code too.

Comment: @MishikoMaisuradze: Please add relevant code *and context* to the question itself so it's actually readable.

Answer (score 0):

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TABLE1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.TABLE1
     CREATE TABLE dbo.TABLE1 
     (ACC_ID    INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
    ,DT    SMALLDATETIME
    ,DR    NUMERIC(20,4)
    ,CR    NUMERIC(20,4)
    PRIMARY KEY (ACC_ID,DT))
    DECLARE @VAR INT = 0
    WHILE @VAR < 100
    BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE1(DT,DR,CR)
    SELECT '2014-01-05',20+@VAR^2,@VAR + 100
    SET @VAR = @VAR  + 1
    END`